# How can I embed videos?

Tags: iframe, embed

How can I **embed** videos from this site https://en7.sportplus.live/
or
How can I get a portion of this site in **iframe**?

Comment: Using `<iframe>` tag in HTML? But judging by the type of site they might have iframe from cross-origin disabled.

Comment: yes its referrer policy: strict-origin when cross origin. That's why I'm asking for expert advice how to embed video from this site..

Comment: Unless they provide users with a link that they can embed then you cannot.